# Cypress: make fixtures ready for commands before hook

Tags: javascript, typescript, cypress

I want to load my fixtures file once and make it available for all other project files.

So, I wrote the following fixtures.js file:

```
let fixturesData;

export const loadFixturesData = () => {
    cy.fixture('../fixtures/example.json').then((data) => {
        cy.log('Fixtures loaded');
        fixturesData = data;
    });
};

export { fixturesData };
```

And I wrote this in the commands.js:

```
import { loadFixturesData, fixturesData } from './fixtures';

before(() => {
    
    loadFixturesData();
  
    // Wait for fixtures to load before accessing them
    cy.wait(() => Object.keys(fixturesData).length > 0);
  
    // Log all fixtures keys and values
    Object.entries(fixturesData).forEach(([key, value]) => {
      cy.log(`Key: ${key}, Value: ${value}`);
    });
});
```

In order to make it available to commands other files as well.

I tried also this without luck:

```
before(() => {
    // Load fixtures data before running any tests
    loadFixturesData().then(() => {
        // Log all keys and values
        Object.entries(fixturesData).forEach(([key, value]) => {
            cy.log(`Key: ${key}, Value: ${JSON.stringify(value)}`);
        });
    });
});
```

but I get:

> Cannot convert undefined or null to object

on the Object.entries line, or

> Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'then')

on the then option

Why. How to solve this?

Answer (score 4):

The simplest way to do it is import the fixture directly in each spec.

```js
import fixture from '../fixtures/example.json'

it('has fixture', () => {
  expect(fixture.email).to.eq('hello@cypress.io')
})

it('also has fixture', () => {
  expect(fixture.email).to.eq('hello@cypress.io')
})
```

[image]

Your code has some bugs, for example `cy.wait(() => Object.keys(fixture).length > 0)` generates this error message

> `cy.wait()` only accepts a number, an alias of a route, or an array of aliases of routes. You passed: undefined